# kivy magnetic animation effect

Tags: python, animation, kivy

[image]

I am trying to teach students with a simple app.
I have made two apples draggable, but can't figure out which function I have to use to make an animating effect that colored apples fit in to the same gray-colored apple.

Here's my code that I had made until now.

**mn.py**

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class apple_0(DragBehavior,Widget):
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        return super(apple_0, self).on_touch_move(touch)

class apple_1(DragBehavior,Widget):
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        return super(apple_1, self).on_touch_move(touch)


class base_0(Image):
    def basepicture_0(self):
        pass

class mn(Widget):
    pass

class mnApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return mn()

if __name__=='__main__':
    mnApp().run()
```

**mn.kv**

```
<mn>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: root.width,root.height
            pos: 0,0

    Label:
        pos: 30, root.top- 70
        text:
            ('[size=20][color=000000]'
            'fnc_slide_0'
            '[/color][/0ize]')
        markup: True

    apple_0:
        id: apple_0_id
        pos: root.width/3,root.height/8
        auto_bring_to_front: True

    apple_1:
        id: apple_1_id
        pos: root.width/5,root.height/8
        auto_bring_to_front: True

    base_0:
        id: base_0_id
        pos: root.width/7, root.height/3


<apple_0>:
    size: 75,75
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'apple_0.png'

<apple_1>:
    size: 75,75
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'apple_1.png'

<base_0>
    size: 944, 502
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'base_0.png'
```

Comment: Afaik, there's no such thing as magnet behavior _directly_ under Kivy, but there's [`garden.magnet`](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.magnet), which at least from the video seems to have the logic you need, although probably not out-of-box, so a little bit of work will be needed.